# Is there any way to develop Outlook add-ins for server side using C#?

Tags: c#, office365, exchange-server

I have developed (using C#) an Outlook add-in, which implements some rules on client side.

It receives each incoming mail, and if it fits some rules it locates it in a specific folder. The main issue is that it works fine, only when outlook client is open on user pc. If it is closed it does not work, because it is triggered on client's pc.

I wonder if it can get developed or moved somehow on server side (Microsoft 365 Exchange Server), so it works 24/7.

Comment: how would a server be able to run a DLL installed on your pc?   You can write some level of rules for exchange (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/ff597938(v%3Dexchg.80) as an example) but, there could be limitations on the exchange server

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I wonder if I can add this DLL (or any other solution) on the server, and remove it from my pc.

Comment: the outlook DLL is for outlook so no, but the link was how to make some server side things

Answer (score 0):

How complicated is the logic in code you have written ? eg a lot of the logic your talking about can be done in Office365 using Flow without needing to write any code (you can even write custom connectors for more advanced logic). You won't be able to use the Outlook code you have written but you can do the same thing using either the Microsoft Graph API and Webhooks to listen to incoming email and then use the Graph operations to perform whatever logic you have (host the app on Azure etc or even can be a server-less function hosted on Azure or AWS) or using EWS Notifications https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/notification-subscriptions-mailbox-events-and-ews-in-exchange

Comment: Down vote from me. This does not answer the question and also the attempted solutions only partially works. For example encrypted emails cannot be checked by flow or office 365 and actions taken. May code running in desktop apps never be replaced by all this controlled stuff Microsoft has introduced.